How to transfer a keras model to onnx format in sagemaker studio?
I am studying how to use tensorflow, onnx in sagemaker studio. I have a code:
tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model_f, 
                           output_path="2024-08-22-autocat-default.onnx", 
                           opset=14, 
                           extra_opset=[helper.make_opsetid('ai.onnx.contrib', 1)]);

here, model_f is the name of the keras mdoel. 2024-08-22-autocat-default.onnx is the name of the onnx format. The above code runs well in sagemaker jupyter lab. But, when I run it in sagemaker studio, it has the error:
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute '_get_save_spec'

The versions of the packages in sagemaker jupyter lab and sagemaker studio are the same.
Could anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

This issues seems to originate from TF / Keras (see the issue mentioned on Github). Can you provide a full output of pip freeze and/or conda list in both environments?
